# Why is "this" in lambda capture treated differently than pointer to the same object?

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, capture, this-pointer

If I capture the "this"-ptr in a lambda I can call member functions without problems. However, when I instead capture the pointer explicitely (without mentioning "this"), it stops working. Am I doing something wrong? According to my understanding, the pointers should be the very same, so this really surprised me. Is there some compiler magic going on to treat "this" in a special way?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:36,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:36),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Astruct+client%0A%7B%0A%0A++++auto+foo(std::string%26%26+other)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25s!!%5Cn%22,+other.data())%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void+local()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++std::string+str+%3D+%22Hello+World+this+is+a+sentence+to+long+for+sso!!%22%3B%0A++++++++auto+lambda+%3D+%5Bthis,+other+%3D+std::move(str)%5D()+mutable+%7B%0A++++++++++++foo(std::move(other))%3B%0A++++++++%7D()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++static+auto+external(void*+ptr)+%7B%0A++++++++std::string+str+%3D+%22Hello+World+this+is+a+sentence+to+long+for+sso!!%22%3B%0A%0A++++++++client*+conv_ptr+%3D+static_cast%3Cclient*%3E(ptr)%3B%0A++++++++auto+lambda+%3D+%5Bconv_ptr,+other+%3D+std::move(str)%5D()+mutable+%7B%0A++++++++++++foo(std::move(other))%3B%0A++++++++%7D()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++client+c1%3B%0A++++c1.local()%3B%0A%0A++++client::external(static_cast%3Cvoid*%3E(%26c1))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.825065274151434,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.174934725848566,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

struct client
{

    auto foo(std::string&& other)
    {
        printf("%s!\n", other.data());
    }

    void local()
    {
        std::string str = "Hello World this is a sentence to long for sso!";
        auto lambda = [this, other = std::move(str)]() mutable {
            foo(std::move(other));
        }();
    }

    static auto external(void* ptr) {
        std::string str = "Hello World this is a sentence to long for sso!";

        client* conv_ptr = static_cast<client*>(ptr);
        auto lambda = [conv_ptr, other = std::move(str)]() mutable {
            foo(std::move(other));
        }();
    }
};

int main()
{
    client c1;
    c1.local();

    client::external(static_cast<void*>(&c1));
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:15:14: error: 'void lambda' has incomplete type
   15 |         auto lambda = [this, other = std::move(str)]() mutable {
      |              ^~~~~~
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:25:16: error: cannot call member function 'auto client::foo(std::string&&)' without object
   25 |             foo(std::move(other));
      |             ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Yes, capturing `this` makes it implicit inside the lambda. Capturing some arbitrary pointer does not.

Comment: @molbdnilo It would be nice if you could do something like: `[this = conv_ptr, other = std::move(str)](){...}` to redefine what "this" is inside the closure

Comment: The `void` type is an *incomplete type* that cannot be completed. Consequently, objects of type `void` are disallowed.  Which is why the `void lambda;` is tripping an **error**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The return type of `client::foo` is `void`, and you're assigning the return values of it to the two `lambda`s. The variable name `lambda` is confusing, since the right hand side of the assignment is actually an immediately invoked lambda expression, not just a lambda.
2. In the second lambda, since `this` is not captured, the compiler does not have a way to call `foo` anymore. Since the intention is to call `foo` via the pointer `conv_ptr`, use it explicitly.

   To quote from [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) on cppreference:

   > For the purpose of name lookup, determining the type and value of the `this` pointer and for **accessing non-static class members**, the body of the closure type's function call operator or operator template is considered **in the context of the lambda-expression**.

   Therefore, for class members that are accessible by `this->member_name`, the `this->` part can be omitted, as it can also be omitted in the context of the lambda-expression, which is within a member function of the class. However, this does not apply to the `conv_ptr` pointer, since `conv_ptr->foo()` does not mean the same thing as `foo()` (which is equivalent to `this->foo()`) in the context.

To make the code compile, remove the invocations `()` from both lambdas, and call `foo` using `conv_ptr->foo`.

```cpp
#include <string>

struct client
{

    auto foo(std::string&& other)
    {
        printf("%s!\n", other.data());
    }

    void local()
    {
        std::string str = "Hello World this is a sentence to long for sso!";
        auto lambda = [this, other = std::move(str)]() mutable {
            foo(std::move(other));
        };
    }

    static auto external(void* ptr) {
        std::string str = "Hello World this is a sentence to long for sso!";

        client* conv_ptr = static_cast<client*>(ptr);
        auto lambda = [conv_ptr, other = std::move(str)]() mutable {
            conv_ptr->foo(std::move(other));
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    client c1;
    c1.local();

    client::external(static_cast<void*>(&c1));
}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YEn9qzd3z)